# Why all react components changes height instead of one

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, components

I'm making a Trello copy, and I have   component rendered few times, also I have a button at end of the  component which should change state and show the input field with another button, that looks like this: [before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJcKV.png)

But problem is that when I click 'add another item' height changes for all  components, like this:
[after click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vngYe.png)

But it should only for one, any ideas?

Css code for container:

```
  listCointainer: {
   display: 'flex',
   justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
```

and for list:

```
list: {
        minWidth: '300px',
        backgroundColor: '#EBECF0',
        margin: '10px',
        paddingBottom: '10px',
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
list: {
        minWidth: '300px',
        backgroundColor: '#EBECF0',
        margin: '10px',
        paddingBottom: '10px', 
        height: 'fit-content'
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved problem! Just to mention it should be fit-content instead of fitContent.